# Why does it keep crashing?

Tags: c

Any idea on when I choose to add a client and as soon as I enter in a client ID the program crashes for that entry?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct client
{
    int clID;
    char cname;
    char caddress;
    char cemail;
    int cfees;
    int ceID;
    char cename;
}typedef client;

struct employee
{
    int empID;
    char ename;
    double erate;
    double ehours;
    double esalary;
    int ecID;
}typedef employee;

void mainMenu();
void clientMenu();
void empMenu();
void getClient(client* pcli);
void getEmp(employee* pemp);
void payroll(employee* pemp);
void dispPay(employee* pemp);
void dispClient(client* pcli);
void dispEmployee(employee* pemp);

int main()
{
    client cli[100];
    client* pcli = &cli[0];
    employee emp[20];
    employee* pemp = &emp[0];
    int answer = -1;
    int mchoice;
    int cchoice;
    int echoice;
    int ccount;
    int ecount;
    int input[9];
    int* psearchclientID;
    int i;

printf("Do you wish to start the program? 1 for yes 2 for no: ");
scanf("%d", &answer);
if(answer ==1)
{
    while(mchoice != 3)
    {
        mainMenu();
        scanf("%d", &mchoice);
        switch(mchoice)
        {
        case 1: while(cchoice != 3)
        {
            clientMenu();
            scanf("%d", &cchoice);
            switch(cchoice)
            {
            case 1: getClient(pcli + i);
                    ccount++;
                break;
            case 2: printf("Enter the client ID to search for: ");
                    psearchclientID = fgets(input, 9, stdin);
                    strtok(input, "\n");
                    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        if(strcmpi(psearchclientID, (pcli->clID + i)) == 0)
                            printf("Client found at position %d\n", i);
                        else
                            printf("Client not found!");
                    }//end for
                break;
            }//end client switch
        }//end client while
        cchoice = 0;
            break;
        case 2: while(echoice != 4)
        {
            empMenu();
            scanf("%d", &echoice);
            switch(echoice)
            {
            case 1: getEmp(pemp + i);
                    ecount++;
                break;
            case 2: payroll(pemp + i);
                    dispPay(pemp + i);
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            }//end emp switch
        }//end emp while
        echoice =0;
            break;
        }//end switch
    }//end main while
}//end if
else if(answer ==2)
{
    printf("Goodbye!");
    exit(0);
}
return 0;
}//end main

void mainMenu()
{
    printf("1-Client Menu\n"
           "2-Employee Menu\n"
           "3-Quit\n");
    printf("Enter a choice from the menu: ");
}//end mainMenu

void clientMenu()
{
    printf("1-Add a client\n"
           "2-Search client\n"
           "3-Go Back to Main Menu\n");
    printf("Enter a choice from the menu: ");
}//end clientMenu

void empMenu()
{
    printf("1-Add an Employee\n"
           "2-Process an Employee(payroll)\n"
           "3-Search Employee\n"
           "4-Go Back to Main Menu\n");
    printf("Enter a choice from the menu: ");
}//end empMenu
```

This is specifically the code for entering in the client info

```
void getClient(client* pcli)
{
    printf("Enter client ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &pcli->clID);
    printf("Enter client name: ");
    scanf("%s", &pcli->cname);
    printf("Enter client address: ");
    scanf("%s", &pcli->caddress);
    printf("Enter client email: ");
    scanf("%s", &pcli->cemail);
    printf("Enter monthly service fees:" );
    scanf("%d", &pcli->cfees);
}//end getClient

void getEmp(employee* pemp)
{
    printf("Enter employee ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &pemp->empID);
    printf("Enter employee name: ");
    scanf("%s", &pemp->ename);
    printf("Enter employee hourly rate: ");
    scanf("%lf", &pemp->erate);
    printf("Enter employee hours worked: ");
    scanf("%lf", &pemp->ehours);
}//end getEmp

void payroll(employee* pemp)
{
    pemp->esalary = pemp->erate * pemp->ehours;
}//end payroll

void dispPay(employee* pemp)
{
    printf("Employee ID %d\nEmployee Salary: %2.2f\n", pemp->empID, pemp->esalary);
}//end dispPay
```

This is where the information would be displayed

```
  void dispClient(client* pcli)
    {
        printf("Client ID: %d\n Name: %s\n Address: %s\n Email: %s\n Monthly fees: %d\n Employee assigned: %d\n Employee name: %s\n", pcli->clID, pcli->cname, pcli->caddress, pcli->cemail, pcli->cfees, pcli->ceID, pcli->cename);
    }//end dispClient

    void dispEmployee(employee* pemp)
    {
        printf("Employee ID: %d\n Name: %s\n Hourly Rate: %2.2f\n Hours worked: %2.2f\n Salary: %2.2f\n Client(s) assigned: %s\n", pemp->empID, pemp->ename, pemp->erate, pemp->ehours, pemp->esalary, pemp->ecID);
    }//end dispEmp
```

Comment: If you're investigating a crash, it's always useful to include any error output that you're seeing. This helps immensely in diagnosis

Comment: You should improve your title. -1 for that alone.

Answer (score 1):

You don't include `&` (address) operator for `%s` (strings) while reading. For example, in function `getClient`, use
     `printf("Enter employee name: ");`
     `scanf("%s", pemp->ename);`

This is one of the problems in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Your clientMenu `switch` statement to add a client calls:

```
case 1: getClient(pcli + i);
```

It is possible to be in that routine where `i` is uninitialized, so it could be *anything*, and very likely beyond the bounds of your 100 element array. In that case `getClient` will very likely be operating in memory it does not own, making your program liable to crash.

It's possible there's more than that issue at play, as well. As others have stated, more information about the crash would help.